# bash heredoc and code block

Tags: bash, heredoc

Script has to log everyting in it to output and to log file

Like this it works OK:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

some_command_1
((
echo "Some text (in parenthness too)"
echo "Another text without them"
) &2>1 )|tee log.txt
some_command_2
exit 0
```

It outputs to stdin/stderr and to log file as expected.

But this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

some_command_1
((
cat <<EOF
Some text (in parenthness too)
Another text without them

EOF
) &2>1 )|tee log.txt
some_command_2
exit 0
```

Produces an error:

> warning: here-document at line 9 delimited by end-of-file (wanted
> `EOF')

> Another text without them: command not found

> ./tmp.sh: line 11: EOF: command not found

ESCaping like this "(" does nothing.

Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in the line containing `((`.
This double bracket has a special meaning in bash. Your script works for me in Linux if I separate the parentheses into separate lines.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo Start
(
(
cat <<XEOF
Some text (in parenthness too)
Another text without them

XEOF

) &2>1 )|tee log.txt
echo Stop
exit 0
```

Comment: Yes, this way "heredoc with parenthness" works as expected.  Even if write'em on one line, but separate by space, like this: "( (" Thanks!